# Cannot import a font face in my static directory

Tags: css

I am using the following CSS to style text inside of a div:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Evolution';
  src: ('/static/Evolution.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.logo {
    font-family: 'Evolution', 'Arial', 'Times New Roman';
}
```

It's not working, though. I can access the font by going to localhost:8000/static/Evolution, so I do not think that the URL src is wrong, is it?
Any other ideas of what could be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `url`:

```
src: url('/static/Evolution.ttf') format('truetype');
     ^^^
```